# Psi-classes on moduli spaces of weighted curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, stacks, birational-geometry, divisors

Let $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,A[n]}$ be the stack of weighted genus $g$ curves with weights $A[n]=(a_1,...,a_n)$, and let $\pi:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,A[n]}$ be the universal curve with sections $\sigma_i:\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,A[n]}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$.

The psi-classes are defined as $\psi_i = c_1(\sigma_i^{*}\omega_{\pi})$ for $i=1,...,n$.

It is known that if $A[n] = (1,...,1)$, that is $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,A[n]}\cong \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$, then $\psi_i$ is nef and big.

Are the classes $\psi_i$ nef and big on $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,A[n]}$ for any vector of weights $A[n]$ ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the moduli space with weights $(1,\dots,1)$ admits a unique morphism to each moduli space $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,A[n]}$ that is an isomorphism on the "interior".  Is the $\psi_i$-class on $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ equal to the pullback of the $\psi_i$-class on $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,A[n]}$?  If so, then $\psi_i$ is big and nef on $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,A[n]}$.  The pullback of a divisor class by a projective, birational morphism is big and nef if and only if the original divisor class is big and nef.

Comment: Yes, that's right, there is always a birational morphism $\rho:\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}\rightarrow\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,A[n]}$ given by lowering the weights. However, I do not know if $\rho^{*}\psi_i = \psi_i$. Perhaps something could happen when different marked points are allowed to collide.